# Cannot read eslintrc config file, stripComments is not found

Tags: npm, webpack, eslint, eslintrc, npm-run

Im struggling with an `npm run build` (webpack) step. Locally on my machine its building fine. But on the remote build im getting an error when it tries to build the eslint module.

The error is as follows: 
`ERROR in ./app/app.module.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read config file: D:\a\1\s\.eslintrc.json
Error: stripComments is not a function`

From digging into it. I have a feeling its some dependency that I have installed locally but the remote build doesnt have it. Ive tried clearing the npm cache, deleting my local npm modules. But I cant seem to repro on my local machine.That function seems to come from `strip-json-comments` lib, I added it as a dependency but still no dice.

Any ideas? Help to get this error solved? Thanks!

Heres my package.json..

```
{
  "name": "My Dummy App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Some Private Package": "^1.3.23",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?